# Need good calculation to get right index by x from width

Tags: javascript, math, mathjs

[image]

Here, I made a canvas app with total width is (742px), so here what I need, I just want to calculate and get right section (Index) by X only.

Example, I got `393.9015504531791` as X calculated with whole width, So X here it's `0.5x` in real, how do I would calculate that and get right Index between (1-17) only through X?
[image]

I tried many calcs I know, but honestly I'm not good on Math lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OneWidth = 542 / 17
LeftEdge = (742 - 542) / 2
Index = Math.floor((X - LeftEdge) / OneWidth) + 1
```